# View isn't updated after changing model

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I'm trying to implement a model/view architecture in my program but the view isn't updated after changing the model, though I think it automatically should be.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```cpp
QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel;
QListView *view = new QListView;

view->setModel(model);

QStringList list;
list << "a" << "b" << "c";

model->setStringList(list);
model->stringList() << "d";
```

Problem is, my view only contains a, b and c. But not d. Why? I thought the view would automatically be updated after changing the model, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Dou you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the last line. `model->stringList()` returns a **copy** of the `QStringList` used as the model, so you only modify the copy, the one used for the model remains unchanged.

Use something like this:

```
QStringList list = model->stringList();
list << "d";
model->setStringList(list);
```

That will work, although `setStringList()` will cause a complete, potentially expensive model reset. However, there seems to be no way around that with `QStringListModel`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But as you said, it's not optimized because of the entire model reset. Isn't there any better alternative?

Comment: A better alternative is to not use QStringList, but instead write your own subclass of QAbstractListModel. In there, you can then use beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() to add new items without a complete model reset.

Comment: You can also use `QStandardItemModel`. It's simple and efficient enough.